# Remove kubernetes cluster information from kubectx workflow

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

Is there a way to remove kubernetes cluster contexts from [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx)? Or can this only be done by manually removing them from kubeconfig?

Comment: UPDATE: it looks like this is a work in progress for kubectx? https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/issues/23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "delete" command for kubectx. You can see the kubectx  help with `kubectx --help`

For reference, the syntax is

```
kubectx -d <NAME> [<NAME...>]
```

eg, `kubectx -d` followed by one or more Kube context names.